# scp adding a random slash

Tags: linux, scp

I have a few files to copy from local PC to remote server. I perform the following command:

```
scp -r /home/user/subdir/* user@server:/var/www/html/
```

I get an error on one file coping /home/user/subdir/somefile.js

```
scp: /var/www/html//somefile.js: Permission denied
```

The rest of the files and subdirectories copy correctly. Why does this one file get an extra "/"? And how do I get it to work correctly?

Comment: The extra slash [doesn't matter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1919/108618).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the slash is your problem.  If you log into user@server and run `ls -l` on `/var/www/html/somefile.js` I suspect you'll find it's owned by a different user or has permissions that won't let you change it.  That's the real source of your probblems.

Comment: I managed to solve it by scp-ing to another directory & then run an ssh script to sudo move it. no errors.